# MVC 4 Dynamic Radio Buttons and Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Options

```
Public Class VariationOptions


        Public Property OptionID As Integer

        Public Property Name As String

        Public Property Price As Double
 End Class
```

Variation class

```
Public Class Variation


    Public Property VariationID As Integer

    Public Property UrunID As Integer

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property inputType As String

    Public Property Options As IList(Of VariationOptions)


End Class
```

I am select variations of product in database.

I want the list this variations with checkbox and radio button.

How to list this inputs and how to request selected values ?

Example picture

[image]

View

```
@ModelType OnlineSiparis.Product

<script type="text/javascript">
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
}
</script>

  @Using (Html.BeginForm("AddProductToCart", "restaurants",Nothing,FormMethod.Post))

  @<div class="row1-1 bgBordo">

      @Html.DisplayTextFor(Function(m) m.Name)
      @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.Price)
      @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.Name)

             <div class="right" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="~/Content/images/Icons/close20.png" onclick="HideVariation();" /></div>
               <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
     @<div class="box">
              <div class="smallbox">
             <div class="smallcolumn1-4  left">
            Quantity
                  </div>
            <div class="smallcolumn2-4  left">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Qty, New With{.onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"})
                  </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>


       @For j As Integer = 0 To Model.Variations.Count-1



     @<div class="smallbox">

         <div class="smallcolumn1-4  left">
                   @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.Variations(j).Name)
         </div>

         <div class="smallcolumn2-4 left">

            @For i As Integer=0 to Model.Variations(j).Options.Count-1


                  @<div class="variationName left">

                          @If Model.Variations(j).inputType = "radio" Then

                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.AddSelectedVariation, Model.Variations(j).Options(i).OptionID)

                          End If


                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.Variations(j).Options(i).Name)
               </div>
              @<div class="variationPrice left">
                  @string.Format("{0:C}",  Model.Variations(j).Options(i).Price  )
                  </div>

        @<div class="clear"></div>
              @<br /> 

                Next




        </div>


        <div class="clear"></div>


   </div>


             Next


            <div class=" textcenter"><input type="submit" class="btnYesil"  value="Ekle" /></div>


        </div>
       End Using
```

Comment: I used this .

@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.Variations(j).Options(i), Model.Variations(j).Options(i))

but all radio groups are checked now. 
changed with this 

 @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.Variations(j).Options(i), Model.Variations(j).Options(i), New With{.checked="false"})

But still selected